EnsureFunds Async in Salesforce Order Management System not able to capture balance for 2 failed invoices on 1 order
So the use case is , I am trying to capture funds for an order using Ensure Funds Async connect ap provided by salesforce . There is this 1 common patter which i am seeing is whenever we have 2 failed invoices on an order and we retry for capture , We trigger the request to capture and get payments and payment gateway log too for both invoice but among 2 invoices only 1 invoice balance moves down to zero although we have captured full amount originally .
For replicating this in your org :
List<invoice> inv =[select id,referenceEntityId from invoice where referenceentity.id='1OsWe0000011ME1KAM']; //Referenceentity id = order summary id
System.debug(inv);
for(Invoice invoice : inv) 
{   
    ConnectApi.EnsureFundsAsyncInputRepresentation input = new ConnectApi.EnsureFundsAsyncInputRepresentation();
    input.invoiceId = invoice.id;
    ConnectApi.EnsureFundsAsyncOutputRepresentation result = ConnectApi.OrderSummary.ensureFundsAsync(invoice.referenceEntityId, input);
    System.debug('BGId :: '+result.backgroundOperationId + ' for Invoice Id :: ' +invoice.id);
}

I have already tried multiple ensure funds connect api too results are same .
Has anyone come across this issue ?
